# How to fix screen orientation to landscape for my windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to configure the windows phone to be fixed to only landscape mode, I there any possibility to do it with C# so that I should be able to get the consistent behaviour across the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it via C#

```
this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `SupportedOrientations` property of all pages to `Landscape`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyWindowsPhone.Page"
   ... other attributes omitted
   SupportedOrientations="Landscape">
<!-- controls go here -->
</UserControl>
```